# Compounded control statement does not function properly

Tags: java, if-statement

A self-written method in my android application consists of a rather compounded control statement:

```
private int getNextIndex() {
    int output = 0;
    int relativeIndex;
    Boolean foundActive = false;
    int size = lessonList.size();                                                               
    for (int i = 1; i <= (size - currentIndex - 1); i++) {
         if (lessonList.get(currentIndex + i).getActive()) {
             output = currentIndex + i;
             foundActive = true;                                                                
             break;
         }
    }
                                                                                       
    if (foundActive = false) {                                                                  
        for (int j = 0; j < currentIndex; j++) {
             if (lessonList.get(j).getActive()) {
                    output = j;
                    foundActive = true;
                    break;
             }
        }
    }                                                                                                    

    if (foundActive = false){
           output = currentIndex;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Unfortunately, for reasons unclear to me **the second, conditional loop is never executed**, even if the first loop did not use the "break" statement (and therefore "foundActive" is still equal to "false"). I haven't tested if the third condition is ever reached, but have good reason to believe it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

`=` is the assignment operator, not the equality check operator. In both `if`s, `foundActive` is assigned with a `false` value. The return value of this assignment is also `false`, so the condition is not entered. Instead, you should use the `==` operator to check `if (foundActive == false)`, or more simply `if (!foundActive)`.

Comment: Simple, but couldn't figure it out myself. Thank you!